# how to prevent growing activity stack in android

Tags: android

I read somewhere that each time you call startActivity() to transition to a new screen, you are creating a new instance of that activity. This immediately raised a red flag to me.

In search of a way to prevent this issue, I read about using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT. However I'm a little alarmed that this method is not used in any of the tutorials I've seen for opening a new screen in your app. So I think I might be missing something. I mean wouldn't you always want to make sure you're not creating a duplicate Activity? isn't this kind of a big deal and shouldn't tutorials address it?

I just want to make sure that I am understanding, and dealing with, this issue correctly, and using the commonly practiced way to transition between screens.

I understand in some cases you open a screen, do something, then close it using finish() and go back. But if an app has a complex 4 level hierarchy , and the user needs to be able to jump around between the screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean wouldn't you always want to make sure you're not creating a duplicate Activity

Most of the time you probably won't want to have two instances of the same `Activity` but I suppose there are situations where someone might

> isn't this kind of a big deal and shouldn't tutorials address it

It is definitely something that Android developers need to know about and understand how to use. I would imagine that you may not see a lot of it in tutorials because most of them teach you the basics to get you started. When a developer is new to Android, they typically have enough to learn about the framework. And they normally show you how to do a few screens (which is often all someone may need). They expect you to learn more of the details by reading through the docs and using websites such as SO

> I understand in some cases you open a screen, do something, then close it using finish() and go back. But if an app has a complex 4 level hierarchy , and the user needs to be able to jump around between the screens?

Yes, a lot of times you won't be getting too deep because the deeper the easier it is to get a "lost" feeling. This is why I like using `Activities` with a `Dialog Theme` when possible. It gives the feeling that you aren't actually leaving the screen you are on. However, that doesn't really answer your question. There are many flags that can be used with `Intents` to keep the stack from growing. The one you mentioned works and I also use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_Top` quite often if I need to clear all `Activities` from the stack and get back to one single `Activity`. There can be so many different situations between apps, users, and developers that how you transition and work the flow or navigation just depends on what you (really, the user) needs.

It seems like you are on the right track by asking these questions. Think about what will give the user the best and most natural experience and find the right flags in the [Intent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for your situation

I hope this cleared things up for you a little. If you don't understand something, feel free to ask

Answer (score 2):

You usually want to avoid creating a duplicate activity, and IMHO, it's a bug in the Android system that the default behavior is to allow it.

(Sometimes you do want to allow it, e.g. you've written a "get filename" activity, and more than one application is likely to call it.)

You control activity creation in two places:  In the manifest, and in the flags of the intent that launches it.

In the manifest, the <activity> tag has the attribute `android:launchMode`, which can be one of:

- "**standard**"
  Default. Can be instantiated multiple times, can  belong to any task, and can appear anywhere on the  stack.  Normally part of the task that called  startActivity() unless the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK was  used.  A new instance of the class is created to respond  to each new intent.
- "**singleTop**"   Identical to standard, except that if the target task already has an instance of this activity at the top of the stack, a new activity will not be created. Instead, the existing activity will receive a call to onNewIntent().
- "**singleTask**"   There can be only one. It's the first activity of a new stack, and is thus the root of an activity stack. If there are more intents, they'll be sent to onNewIntent().
- "**singleInstance**" Identical to singleTask, except that it's the only activity in its stack. If it tries to launch a new activity, the new activity will start a new task. Same as if FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK was in the intent.

Answer (score 1):

I personally find the history back stack in android more confusing than helpful to end users. The use of back buttons can often not do what the user expects.

There are a few options available to you if you want to use activities as the main construct.

1. For workflow type activities (e.g. capture forms) start the first activity with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and at the end use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
2. For top level activities that are often a returning point start the activity with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. This basically checks if the activity is already somewhere in the stack and if it is pops off every activity above it in the stack and resumes the original activity.

Another possible method for the top level activities is to use one top level activity and use fragments for moving around, e.g. tab browser etc. Then just use activities for actual separate tasks.

Comment: "if you want to use activities as the main construct"... What other constructs are there?

Comment: I just meant that for some small applications where there isn't much workflow it can be easier to use a single main activity as a container for fragments and swap fragments instead of starting new activities. Its a bit offtopic though and doesn't really address the op problem.